Possessive pronoun or possessive adjective when giving options, only one of which is first-person
I thought that I knew when to use "my" and "mine" respectively. However I was writing an email to ask a someone to visit either me or my colleague at work and now I'm not so sure.
Is it:
A. "Please come by mine or NN's office when [...]"
Or, is it:
B. "Please come by my or NN's office when [...]"
I've thought for too long about this and now both versions seem perfectly cromulent and obviously wrong at the same time, so I'm asking the experts. Maybe both are wrong?
(For transparency: I have already rephrased my email to avoid this issue and sent it off. I.e. I'm not looking for suggestions on how to rephrase this, I already have. I would simply like to know which, if either, is correct.)

"Please come by my office or NN's [office]." The only context in which mine would be appropriate is if you said "NN's office or mine".

I recently had occasion to write I think yours and my answer are essentially saying the same thing. Personally, I find yours much better than your in such contexts, but opinions differ. And I'd say the same about yours and my answer (I don't like your and my answer).

A quick on line search for "my mine difference" will give you an explanation, of which the following is a synopsis.
My is a possessive adjective that modifies a noun to indicate ownership. For example "My office".
Mine is a possessive pronoun indicating ownership that stands alone without a noun. For example "This office is mine".
So B is the correct version.
Note. I'm using the Brave browser which has built in AI that tries to answer such questions and has it's own search engine as default.
